# Как "заставить" браузер "слушать" сервер?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, javascript

Доброго времени суток, сообщество. Столкнулся с проблемой, которая и прозвучала в заголовке. Как можно реализовать в web-приложении прослушку сообщений с сервера и, собственно, как заставить сервер отправлять сообщения на определенный адрес средствами php?

Comment: [web application messaging protocol](http://wamp.ws/)

Comment: почитайте вот тут http://www.askdev.ru/question/10889/PHP-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-WebSockets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP подразумевает запуск скрипта по запросу пользователя. Т.е. пока его не пнут, он не полетит. А вам же нужно, чтобы приложение само в какой-то момент проснулось и сделало что-то.

В принципе что-то такое можно сделать и на PHP. Например, дёргать cron-ом скрипт, который при каждом запуске проверяет, не надо ли послать клиенту сообщение, и посылает его (адовый костыль), или вместо cron-а использовать самого клиента (с некоторыми уточнениями это будет long poll, который упоминали выше). Для каких-то задач этого может вполне хватить, но в целом это не годится.

Правильным решением будет использование демонической серверной части. Т.е. не скрипты, запускаемые на каждый запрос, а демон, работающий постоянно (кстати, такую манеру бекэнд программирования предполагают все распространённые языки программирования, кроме php, php - последний бастион cgi). Предложенный выше Node.JS - лишь один из вариантов (надо заметить, что этот вариант сейчас очень модный). По сути, демон можно написать на любом более-менее вменяемом ЯПе (некоторые умельцы на php пишут :).

Думаю, стоит уточнить, что не обязательно переписывать весь бекэнд, будет достаточно реализовать в демоне только тот функционал, который плохо реализуется силами основного приложения.

Comment: long po**l**l, "долгий опрос".

Comment: Мне стыдно.

Answer (score 4):

Две технологии используются: либо web-sockets (http://socket.io/), либо лонг полы.
кошернее сокеты, потому что тогда нет постоянного долбежа запросами, а есть «прослушивание».

Comment: Один запрос от пользователя раз в полминуты - это не проблема (он сам за это время пять запросов осуществит). Проблема - это то, что всё это время на каждое подключение висит по копии скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе нечего сложного, простейшая схема может выглядеть следующим образом:

1. На стороне клиента, на сервер периодически отправляются [ajax запросы](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), запрашивающие новые сообщения.
2. На стороне сервера, соответствующий контроллер отрабатывает входящие ajax запросы, возвращая нужный респонс

В вашем случае, серверу не нужно совершать каких-либо запросов, так как сообщения будут переданы клиенту в качестве респонса на его запрос.

Для лучшего понимания, пожалуйста ознакомитесь со [спецификацией HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

Comment: @erbolking Это не совсем то. Хочется минимизировать нагрузку на сервер. В С++, скажем, для этого используются соккеты. Может кто знает, есть ли что-то подобное для javascript и php?

Comment: @OlegFM, замечательное сравнение, но все-таки нужно понимать, в каких границах предполагается осуществление задумки. HTTP не предполагает общение вне HTTP, относительно недавно появились Websockets, которые, по факту, вам выше wamp'ом и предложили. Язык тут не при чем, сокеты же вообще открываются ОС и существуют довольно независимо от языка. Есть всякие способы типа общения через flash, но это в основном костыли, которые трудно кроссбраузерно возвести.

Comment: Все, всем спасибо. За вчерашний вечер и утро нагуглил, что есть библиотека ***Socket.IO***, основанная на WebSockets, правда, предназначена она под ***Node.JS***. Пойду курить мануалы.